# Inner line not removed from circle in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Right now I am playing around with Canvas and its features, however I am experiencing a weird problem. I am currently trying to draw a circle inside of a Triangle made of several "lineTo's". My problem being when I just implement an arc; it draws the Circle but with a line from the center and out towards the right side (angle 0). If I enclose my arc in beginPath and closePath it draws it perfectly however the Triangle disappears (JSFiddle is provided). Why is this happening also am I doing something specifically wrong? I am new to Canvas and I want to learn, thank you in advance!

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/720hg2aq/1/

```
// Draw Triangle
ctx.moveTo((width*0.4), (height*0.05));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.6), (height*0.05));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.6), (height*0.05));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.5), (height*0.15));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.5), (height*0.15));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.4), (height*0.05));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.5), (height*0.09));
// End of Triangle

// Begin Circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc((width*0.5), (height*0.09), 20, 0 , 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
// End Circle

// Draw it out
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beginPath()` method begins a path, or **resets the current path**.

Once you begin a path, use `moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, `quadricCurveTo()`, `bezierCurveTo()`, `arcTo()`, or `arc()` to make the path, then `storke()` it.

So the code should be:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

// Draw Triangle
ctx.beginPath(); /// Let's start the work!
ctx.moveTo((width*0.4), (height*0.05));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.6), (height*0.05));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.6), (height*0.05));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.5), (height*0.15));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.5), (height*0.15));
ctx.lineTo((width*0.4), (height*0.05));

ctx.moveTo((width*0.5), (height*0.09));
ctx.stroke(); /// Brushing with your dye!!
// End of Triangle

// Begin Circle
ctx.beginPath(); /// Let's start the **NEW** work!
/// Don't let the previous path be connected with the current path!
ctx.arc((width*0.5), (height*0.09), 20, 0 , 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke(); /// Brushing with your dye!!
// End Circle
```

Comment: ohhh! Thank you so much, I feel so stupid now. I thought I tried something like this out, however I just tried and it worked. So thank you a lot! :D